# Dynamic CRM : Jquery $ajax error in CRM 2013

Tags: jquery, dynamics-crm

I have added button in command bar with the help of "Ribbon workbench".

And this button is calling javascript method, code as below:

```
/// <reference path="new_/Scripts/jquery_1.9.1.js" />
function callPotentialDuplicateService()
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: 'http://*******.svc/MethodName',
            success: function (data) {
                result = data.Result;
                alert(result);

            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Err")
                alert(XMLHttpRequest.status);
            }
        });
    }
```

Now when i try this same in Visual studio, it is working fine. but in CRM its not working.

How should i add jQuery-1.9.1.js file in above method.

Comment: @Tushar, its not showing any error its just blank even i have tried this alert("Error : " + textStatus + ": " + XMLHttpRequest.responseText); and its give me alert of error + blank.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the jQuery script file as part of the action and make the command isNaN.

Include jQuery in the command before you include your custom script file.

[See point number 6 on this blog](http://blog.allegient.com/blog/custom-ribbon-with-crm-ribbon-workbench-quickly-and-easily)